# Can changing the default location of the Microsoft SQL log in server properties cause unexpected behavior or any performance issue?

Tags: sql-server, database, location, sqllong

I have an application which is running on Mulesoft. The application connects to the database for basic authentication. Recently I made a change in the SQL Server properties to locate the default log location from C drive to D drive. I did not change the location for "DATA"and "BACKUP". I only changed for "LOG".
After changing I restarted the SQL Server.
There are 2 issues here after this change.

1. The log remains in the same place which is in the C Drive. It did not reflect the changes.
2. There are some application error which occurs randomly while trying to retrieve the username and password from the database for basic authentication. Meaning there are no issues on first few triggers to the application, but it hits authentication error after few triggers.
   This issue occur only after the SQL location change. I'm not quite sure if it is related.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Off-topic for multiple reasons. Belongs on dba, contains 2 unrelated question. But generally, changing a default option does not affect previously existing things.

Comment: Removing the MuleSoft tag because the client application is not relevant for the question. Mule Runtime uses the MS SQL JDBC driver, if that is useful.